# Javascript - Loop keeps running after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, refresh

Today one of the weirdest things i have ever seens just happened.
I have a loop in a page that does a synchronous ajax request for each element of the loop. Since it was taking too long i decided to stop the loop by refreshing the page.

When the page loaded i couldn't click on any element of the page so i checked Firebug console and i saw that the ajax calls of the previous loop were still being done (the loop is set to start after i click on a link, so it can't start as soon as page loads).
To stop the loop i had to close the current tab and open my page in a new one.

It's worth mentioning that i have a datatables table on that page and i have enabled the option to save the table state, maybe this is interfering with my code (the loop itself is not part of the datatables initialization, though it uses data from the table).

I have also noticed that some things of the loop aren't being done. It should've changed the page of the datatable by time to time, and it should've written in the javascript console, both things don't happen after i refresh the page, the ajax calls are still going though.

Here's the code where the loop is contained:

```
//This variable will contain a reference to the datatable
var oTable;
var isWorking=false;
//Change the datatables page
function changeTablePage(oTable, page, clear){
    if(clear){
        oTable.fnClearTable();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }
    oTable.fnPageChange(page);
}

//This part is inside a document.ready block
    $(document).on("click", ".validation-all-click", function(event){
        if(!isWorking){
            isWorking=true;
            //saves the current page, will be needed for later
            var page=oTable.fnPagingInfo().iPage;
            var numberPage=0;
            var done=false;
            while(!done){
                console.log("page: "+numberPage);
                changeTablePage(oTable, numberPage, false);
                var nNodes = oTable.fnGetNodes();
                var len=nNodes.length;
                $('.validation-click', nNodes).each(function( index, value ){
                    //id of the element to be validated
                    var id=$(value).data("rowid");
                    //Calls the validation url
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/validate?id="+id,
                        async: false
                    });
                });
                //if the datatables page has 0 items, then it's done
                if(len==0){
                    done=true;
                }
                numberPage++;
            }
            //goes back to the original page
            changeTablePage(oTable, page, true);
            isWorking=false;
        }

});
```

I don't want this behavior to happen, but i have no idea on why it's happening and how to prevent it

Comment: It's unlikely that this is the reason you see what you see. If you where to provide a reduced case, somebody might help.

Comment: I have posted the code in which the loop is contained

Comment: Superficially it looks correct. A firbug bug would be on my suspect list. Maybe even a Firefox bug. Still, your approach is wrong. The requests should be asynchronous. I've only used `async: false` for prototyping.

Comment: This loop might be called on datasets of 100k or more, Unless there is a way to queue ajax calls instead of doing them all at once (i admit i never looked for that), If i don't use async: false the browser (or the server even) might freeze or crash. But i fear that queuing ajax calls will bear the same problem of the one i'm having now

Comment: I might add that this was the behavior on Firefox (Pale Moon to be precise), i have just tried the page on Chrome: in this case if i click on refresh the script keeps going but the page won't refresh at all if i click on the refresh button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by adding a variable that will stop the loop when i exit the page:

```
var stopLoop=false
$( window ).unload(function() {
    stopLoop=true;
});
```

both loops will now check if this variable is false before executing the code inside the loop.
This works on Firefox but not on Chrome though.

-- EDIT --

In the end i have solved by editing the code in order to make the ajax calls asynchronous and using the callback functions to continue the cycle, though it was no simple task (some days later i found a new solution that allowed me to do all that i needed in a single call when i found out how to recover the parameters used by datatables to retrieve data, but this has nothing to do with the original question). So, for future references: expect this "weird" behaviour when making a loop with ajax synchronous calls

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your story. I don't see any specific question in the post, so I'll just comment on whatever I feel like.

As I understand it, browsers aren't required to redraw the UI *while* JavaScript is running. Since there's a script blocking on a synchronous ajax request, maybe it's to be expected that you don't see the changes to the table until the loop finishes.

Furthermore, it may also be that the browser isn't required to destroy a page while its scripts are running. That would explain why you saw requests in Firebug after refreshing the page--perhaps the previous copy of the page was still running in a hidden state.

edit: valepu reports in a comment, below, that the table does change while the script is running. That's fine. The browser can probably determine that it can redraw the UI during the ajax call (which doesn't affect the JavaScript environment). valepu also clarifies that the visual updates stop after refreshing the page, though the requests continue to go out. This is also consistent with the idea that the browser has just hidden the previous page (until it finishes) and loaded up a new copy of the page when refreshing.

As for how to prevent it: the most reliable way would be to use asynchronous requests, or otherwise yield between requests. Sorry, folks.

Comment: The "question" is that i don't want this behavior to happen, but i have no idea on why it's happening and how to prevent it. When the script is running after i click on the button that starts the loop, i see the table changing (and the console.log messages), after i refresh the page i still see the ajax calls (both the call for the datatables page and the call in the loop) but i don't see the console message nor the table being updated.